# Subversion statistics list

Tags: svn, statistics

I'm going to write a little library and after the UI for agregating and visualizing statistics from the specified subversion repository. 
My question is: 
What do you need like a developers/leads/managers to see on the statistics ?

Here I put down some initial ideas :

**1**. Commits by author(s)

**2**. Files that were changed by the author(s)

**3**. Changed code lines ratio respect total count of lines in the single file by author(s)/ subfolder(s) => file(s)

**4**. Have a possiblity to create the group of the files (some kind of PROJECT concept virtualisation) in order to validate impact of one author(s) on the specified PROJECT, thow group of files.

All these obviously is calculated over specified timeline chosen by user.

So, something else ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would also like to have commit count by a certain author as well (similar to what is provided by tortoise svn)

**Edit:**

No Problem :)

I would also like, If you brain storm a bit and come up with a way/feature by which I can see the contribution of a author to a project (not just commit count).

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, it's my fault, it's actually the first point no Comments, COMMITS. You are right. Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by saying: way/feature ? Can you give a simple example ? Thanks

Comment: A feature that shows the contribution of a author in a more exhaustive way than just showing me the commit counts are his contribution for the project. Like taking into account % of code written by a author for each module as one factor, think of more such factors that might give the author's contribution to the project. Just a thought .. Thanks

Comment: Ok,I understand, thank you. I agree that something like that will be useful for the user(like code lines changed ratio, commits ratio .. ). By the way if you are interested in to use new tools for the subversion, I can suggest the first one of the suite that we develop.It Subversion repository listener
by it's nature, but manages things in a little bit different way from others. It's open source (GPL) and you can download the binaries and sorce code as well : http://code.google.com/p/svnradar/.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Just use [StatSVN](http://statsvn.org), from the site:

> StatSVN retrieves information from a Subversion repository and
>   generates various tables and charts describing the project
>   development, e.g.
>
> - Timeline for the lines of code
> - Lines of code for each developer
> - Activity by Clock time
> - Authors Activity
> - Author activity per Module
> - Author Most Recent Commits with links to ViewVc
> - Stats per directory
> - File count
> - Average file size
> - Largest files
> - Files with most revisions
> - Directory Sizes
> - Repository Tags Number of LOC per version.
> - Repository tree with file count and lines of code
> - LOC and Churn the evolution of LOC and the amount of change per day
> - Repo Map the dynamic hierarchical view of your repo for the last 30 days

Comment: thanks, just working on that stuff in these days. Hope to be able to deliver something useful till the end of this year. Would be cool.